# Android bouncy castle: IOException

Tags: android, bouncycastle, keystore

I am using Sun's keytool to create a Bouncy castle keystore and import a certificate into it. The keytool does produce a keystore in the Bouncy castle format.

I then attempt to import the Bouncy castle keystore into an Android program. I am able to get an 
instance of the "BKS" keystore but calling load on the keystore throws

```
"java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store".
```

This is the code

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/ArcGIS/mystore.bks");
keyStore.load(is, "abcdef".toCharArray());
```

I tried various versions of the Bouncy castle JAR downloaded from http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Ranjit

Answer (score 22):

It seems the version of BouncyCastle shipped with Android 4.0.3 (API version 15) fails when trying to open keystores produced using the most recent BouncyCastle library. When I created a keystore using `bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar`, my sample Android app failed with the `java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store` error.

However, if the keystore was created with the `bcprov-jdk16-146.jar` library, then it could be loaded by the application. My solution was to create the keystore with this older library.

Presumably this will also be the case for older API versions; try older versions of BouncyCastle when creating the keystore.

Comment: +1 This solved my problem so far.. but it also leads me to the question what happens with devices running android 4.2 as they update it to bouncycastle 1.47 (source: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html )

Comment: That was the solution of my problem too. Thanks for valuable info.

Comment: When I try to use the 146 library to create the certificate it says me exactly the same "wrong keystore version". If I use the latest version it imports ok. on Android Device it occurs exactly the oposite. the problem is that the *.csr certificate come from a server where the client asks to maintain it as it is now.? is there an option I can use without having to regenerate the csr file with older version on server?

Answer (score 4):

Resolved. The keytool command was missing the "-storetype BKS" argument, so although the BKS keystore file was generated, it was probably invalid.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. however I used the argument "-storetype BKS".  Did you try anything else to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to your BKS-certificate password length, it must be less than or equal to 7 characters. This is a matter of U.S. policy and U.S. export controls (not due to technical reasons).

Re-export your certificate using a 7-character lenght and it will work.

Hope it helps