# Making an HTTPS connection using URL.openConnection()

Tags: java, android, https, bouncycastle, keystore

I'm trying to make an HTTPS connection to a [server](https://www.onlinescoutmanager.co.uk) that has a certificate set to expire in April 2013 and uses GlobalSign as the root certificate.

```
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

// Send the POST data
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(postParamString.toString().getBytes("UTF8"));

// Read the reply
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

As it stands, this throws `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate signature.` when `getOutputStream()` is called.

This same site and certificate are valid in the stock HTC web browser and desktop browsers. When I use the same code to access [Google](https://www.google.co.uk) it works (but then complains about a 404 error). Various posts on StackOverflow imply that it should "just work" and others say to set up your own key store (or disable all HTTPS validation!) I assume the difference in behaviour is down to different root key stores in use (Can anyone clarify this?).

I've now tried creating a key store using bouncy castle but I can't get this to load on my device.

After exporting the certificate from Firefox, I create a key store using:

```
keytool.exe -import -alias onlinescoutmanager -file www.onlinescoutmanager.co.uk.crt -storetype BKS -keystore res\raw\keystore
```

This is then loaded and used in the application using:

```
InputStream stream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
// BKS seems to be the default but we want to be explicit
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
ks.load(stream, "www.onlinescoutmanager.co.uk".toCharArray());
stream.close();

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ks);
X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
SSLContext context2 = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context2.init(null, new TrustManager[] { defaultTrustManager }, null);
sslSocketFactory = context2.getSocketFactory();
```

This is failing with `java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store.` when `keystore.Load()` is called.

I have [ensured I'm passing `-storetype BKS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5187509/588306), [used a <=7 character keystore password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528853/588306), added the CA certs to the key store, and using both Bouncy Castle version 1.45 and 1.47 to create the key store with no change in the reported error message.

My environment is Eclipse Juno 4.2.1 with JRE 1.7u9b5 running on Windows 8. The device I'm testing on is an HTC sensation running stock Android 2.3. The application has a minimum SDK version of 7 and a target of 15.

If anyone can explain how to create a valid BKS key store on Windows 8 or how I can get Java to use the same key store as the browser(or system?) that would be appreciated.

You can download the [entire project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j148u838icm4rk5/SGM.zip) as it was at the time of writing, and the [generated keystore](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0cnb8l2m90zyjc3/keystore) if required.

Comment: This is definitely the best formulated question I've ever seen, on any site

Comment: @AndreaLigios I've had to answer a far few, I should know the rules and how to "ask a decent question" :p

Comment: @Deanna when you create the keystore, should you have -trustedcacerts in the options so that it will validate the cert using the trusted certs? (neve worked with BKS guessing based on core java similarities)

Comment: @Deanna apologies, typo. Should be -trustcacerts. Hopefully this works, if not I'll leave it to people who have actually used BKS

Comment: I've tried adding and trusting the two CA certs above it to the keystore too but with the same result :|.

Comment: So the error is occurring on Windows 8? Or on the android device?

Comment: @GregS The erorr is occuring on the Android device. Windows 8 is used for development and to create the key store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bouncy Castle 1.47 is using different version header. Can you try [1.46 version](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk15on/1.46/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar), it should work.

```
keytool -import -alias onlinescoutmanager -file www.onlinescoutmanager.co.uk.crt -storetype BKS -storepass osmosm -keystore C:/keystore -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar
```

Comment: I'm already using 1.45 (I used 1.47 initially, see the question) will 1.46 make a difference? Bear in mind that I'm currently targetting Android 2.3 that seems to use 1.45.

Comment: Hmmm, I did not try with 1.45 version but I can say that your project successfully loads keystore created by 1.46 version.

Comment: Thanks, using 1.46 fixed the version problem. I've written up a full solution/explanation below.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to various people for their hints on this, there are multiple things that all needed to be correct for it to work.

1. If the HTTPS site's certificate is signed by a trusted root certificate then it will work out of the box without a custom `SSLSocketFactory`.
   The trusted root certificates CAN be different to that used by a browser so don't assume that if it works in the Android web browser then it will work in your app.
   If it's not a trusted root certificate and you get exceptions like `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate signature.`, then you need to create and load a key store as below.
2. The key store needs to be generated using the Bouncy Castle provider ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5187509/588306)) by specifying `-storetype bks` on the `keytool` command line.
   If Bouncy Castle is not installed correctly then this will fail with various exceptions including `java.security.KeyStoreException: BKS not found`.
   If the key store is not created with the Bouncy Castle provider then you may get the `java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store.` exception, causing confusion with the next case.
3. You need to use an appropriate version ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10809108/588306), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14116462/588306), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002670/588306)) of the Bouncy Castle provider. In most cases, this seems to be [version 1.46](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk15on/1.46/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar).
   This can be put into your JRE's `lib/ext/` folder and the class name added to `lib/security/java.security`, or specified directly on the command line to `keytool`.
   If it's an incompatible version (or store type) you will get exceptions along the lines of `java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store.` again.
4. You must include all intermediary and the root certificate. If any are missing, you will get a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.` exception.
5. The certificate chain MUST be in order for them to be validated correctly. If they aren't you will either get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: IssuerName(CN=XYZ) does not match SubjectName(CN=ABC) of signing certificate.` or again, a generic `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`
   I have not found a way to order them in the key store so resorted to [doing it in code at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4115101/588306).

Some people have suggested that [using a keystore password longer than 7 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528853/588306) will also cause it to fail, but that's not what I've found.

I think this covers every pitfall I found, but feel free to expand and add linsk to related questions.